Add caption and label for autofit table using resizebox
I have a LaTeX table code as follows (using the Wiley chapter template).
Link: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/book-template-for-wiley-authors/zbfhmmzbhhfr
If I don't add a caption and label, the table compiles beautifully as shown in Figure 1. However, when I add a caption and label, it results in an error as shown in Figure 2.
Please assist me in adding a caption and label to this table.
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{Wiley-AuthoringTemplate}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For \raggedright inside table cells
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % For professional table lines
\usepackage{multirow}  % For multirow handling
\usepackage{array}     % For column width specification
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % For text alignment
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % Add this to your preamble
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % Adjust spacing between rows
 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
%\caption{table caption}.
%\label{tab-llm-code}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|l@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\makecell{Prompt \\ pattern}} & \textbf{\makecell{Template of prompt patterns}} \  \ \midrule
\makecell{System setup} & 
\makecell[l]{You are an expert in the field of Android security, specializing in auditing    Android applications by static analysis. \\ Your task is to combine known information and your expert knowledge to generate a behavior summary \\ for the given Android application in   \{View type\}.} \\ \midrule
 \makecell{Task Description} & 
  \makecell[l]{\texttt{<Task Description>:} \\ 
    You must strictly follow the following steps to analyze the application with the package name \textbf{\{Package\}} \\ and output a summary from \{View type\}: \\ 
 1. First, you get the \{\textit{Feature type}\}'s contents of the application as follows.    \\ 
  \quad 1.1- \{\textit{Feature subtype 1}\}: \{\textit{Function descriptions list 1}\} \\ 
  \quad 1.2- \{\textit{Feature subtype 2}\}: \{\textit{Function descriptions list 2}\} \\ 
 2. Now you have known all contents of \{\textit{Feature type}\} of \{\textit{Package}\}.    \\ 
  You should start a static analysis from \{\textit{View type}\} and generate          \textit{<behavior analysis summary>} \\ for the view based on \textit{<Output Description and Requirements>}.} \\ \midrule
  \makecell{Output Description \\ and Requirements} & 
  \makecell[l]{\texttt{<Output Description and Requirements>:} \\ 
  1. Output description: Interpretation and summary of known information on \{\textit{View type}\}, focusing on behavior \\ about high-risk \{\textit{Feature type}\} and their potential risks. \\ 
 2. When you output the summary, do not add extra descriptions. Just output the content of the summary. \\ 
 3. The output must be concise. \\ 
 4. Provide an objective summary strictly in terms of \{\textit{View type}\}, based on facts and known information. \\ 
 5. If there is missing information in \{\textit{Feature subtype 1}\} or \{\textit{Feature subtype 2}\}, such as an empty list, \\ it means the application has no information about the aspect. \\ 
 6. Your output should be free of extensions and suggestions like ``Further exploration is required.'' Avoid subjective \\ assumptions such as ``There may be plausible explanations,'' which may indicate potential privacy risks or malicious \\ behaviors.} \\ 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
  }

  \end{table}
\end{document}

Figure 1 without the caption and label

Figure 2 with the caption and label

Best regards.

Scaling elements which contain text will almost always give a poor results. Better choose a suitable fontsize ad layout.

And never use vertical lines if you use the booktabs package.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I fix my code. Sorry about this. I don't know.

Can you add a link to where we can get Wiley-AuthoringTemplate.sty from?

THis is the link: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/book-template-for-wiley-authors/zbfhmmzbhhfr

The example on page 27 from the documentation in your link contains an example how too add a label to a table.

Page 27 of AuthoringTemplate_Manual.pdf from your link contains an example which shows how to add a caption/label to a table in with this template.
In addition:

don't scale elements which contain text.
don't use vertical line if you use the booktabs package

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{Wiley-AuthoringTemplate}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{table caption\label{tab-llm-code}}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{2cm}X@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Prompt pattern} & \textbf{Template of prompt patterns}\\ \midrule
System setup & You are an expert in the field of Android security, specializing in auditing    Android applications by static analysis.  Your task is to combine known information and your expert knowledge to generate a behavior summary for the given Android application in   \verb|{View type}|. \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
}{}
\end{table}
\end{document}



It worked with me. Thank you very much madam/sir.
